# Select all open orders from an order table and its associated state table

Tags: database, postgresql

**Premise:**

1. Orders table - id, rate, unit, amount, timestamp
2. Order States table - id, order_id, state, timestamp

Both tables are insert only (no updates)

For each order created, the state table can possibly have one or more states of the order, like 0 for open, 1 for completed etc.

**Purpose:**

1. Retrieve all open orders
2. Retrieve all open orders order by rate desc/asc

The same is currently achieved using subquery, group by and having clause. Also tried joins, group by and having clause.

**Problem:**

Very slow select time - Around 500 to 1000 ms for an order table size of approx a million records.

**Required Help:**

1. Indexing suggestions
2. Query re-write suggestions

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have DISTINCT at the query?

Comment: can you edit the question and add the tables structures (create table statement) including the indexes and the constraints you have.

Comment: please post your SQL

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the tables structure (indexes and constraints). 
If your Order States table  contains every state each order went through and considering the queries you need to run, i would suggest to maintain a table with only the last state (which is the current state too i guess)  of each order and keep the previous states in a history table.

without knowing what you already have

**Orders table**

id: *primary key* (automatically indexed using b-tree)

rate: *indexed* (because you need to sort your result by rate)

**Order States table**

id: *primary key* (automatically indexed using b-tree)

order_id: *foreign key* + *index*

state: *index*

maybe an index *order_id,state* could help too (give it a try)